# Appending a variable to existing data depending on rows

Tags: r

So I have two columns. I need to add a third column. However this third column needs to have A for the first amount of rows, and B for the second specified amount of rows.
I tried adding this data_exercise_3 ["newcolumn"] <- (1:6) 
but it didn't work. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: try this `data_exercice_3['newcolumn'] <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 6))`

Answer (score 0):

```
data_exercise_3$category <- c(rep("A",6),rep("B",6))
```

Comment: so first of all, I would like to add a new column.... then I would like that the first 6 rows of this new column have a letter A and the other 5 rows have a letter B

Comment: Okay then my 1 line of code would be : df$newcol <- c(rep('A',6),rep('B',5))

Comment: I got back an error "Error in df$category <- c(rep("A", 6), rep("B", 5)) : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

Comment: @vicky it's because your data.frame is NOT named `df` but `data_exercice_3`. If you haven't defined `df` by default df is the F distribution density function and R complains because it thinks that you want to 'subset' a function

Comment: @vicky sorry I should have used ur naming convention to make it easier for you. data_exercise_3$category <- c(rep("A",6),rep("B",6))

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're having a problem with subsetting a data frame correctly. I'd recommend reviewing this concept before you proceed much further, either via a [Coursera course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/r-programming/lecture/JDoLX/subsetting-basics) or on a website like [this UCLA R learning module on subsetting data frames](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/modules/subsetting.htm). Subsetting is a crucial component of data wrangling with R, and you'll go much faster with a solid foundation of the basics!

You can assign values to a subset of a data frame by using `[row, column]` notation. Since your data frame is called `data_exercise_3` and the column you'd like to assign values to is called `'newcolumn'`, then assuming you want the first 6 rows as 'A' and the next 3 as 'B', you could write it like this:

```
data_exercise_3[1:6,'newcolumn'] <- 'A'
data_exercise_3[7:9,'newcolumn'] <- 'B'
```