# boxplot between two variables

Tags: r, boxplot

I have the following data

```
structure(list(one = c(15L, 9L, 4L, 34L, 17L, 18L, 14L, 12L, 
13L, 26L, 31L), two = c(31L, 35L, 29L, 28L, 12L, 18L, 30L, 14L, 
22L, 10L, 29L)), .Names = c("one", "two"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

I need to first create a third variable which has the first 6 rows "A" and the other rows"B". I then need to create a boxplot between "one" and this variable. I tried doing

```
boxplot(category ~ one, mydata3, v= TRUE,main="boxplotrelationship")
```

but it won't work. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I just answered part of your question in a [similar question you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37382171/2005219), but here goes!

You have a couple problems here: first, your structure isn't assigned to any variable, so you can't reference it later in a boxplot. Below, see how I've assigned it to `mydata3` first.

Also, since `category` is your grouping variable, it's not `category ~ one`, but the reverse -- `one ~ category`.

```
mydata3 <- structure(list(one = c(15L, 9L, 4L, 34L, 17L, 18L, 14L, 12L, 
                       13L, 26L, 31L), two = c(31L, 35L, 29L, 28L, 12L, 18L, 30L, 14L, 
                                               22L, 10L, 29L)), .Names = c("one", "two"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                              -11L))
mydata3[1:6,'category'] <- 'A'
mydata3[7:11, 'category'] <- 'B'
boxplot(one ~ category, mydata3,v=TRUE,main="boxplotrelationship")
```

Comment: Thanks so much Edward. I realized what I was doing wrong now. Spent a night up trying to figure it out :/

Comment: Awesome @vicky. Please accept the answer if it helped! [how to accept](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png)

Comment: Permit me to ask another question: I'm performing t-tests and I'm getting this error " grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels". it's concerning another data set. Do you know what "levels" is referring to?

Comment: hi vicky, why don't you post a new question and we'll try to help you out! And like you did for this question, try to include the data and code.

Comment: Hi Edward I tried doing so but was told I have to wait 90 mins before I can post another question... still new to this forum so I don't quite understand how it works..